# Remove columns based on their name (first value)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using macros to quickly search a large table of student data and consolidate it into a single cell for use in seating plans (I'm a teacher). Most of it works but I have a problem with selecting just the data I need.

Steps:
1. Remove data.
2. Run a formula to check if students fit into particular groups and consolidate their information
3. Format

Different subjects and year groups have different layouts for their data and so this step is causing me problems. I've tried using absolute cell references in step 2 but this doesn't work as sometimes the information that should be in column D is in column E etc.

What I want to be able to do is have a macro that checks the first value in the column (ie the title) and if it doesn't match one of a predetermined list delete the whole column along with it's data.

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Range("everything")

If rng.Value = "Test" Or rng.Value = "Test1" Then
    rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```

I think I could use something like this if I could change the output from hiding columns to deleting them?

Comment: Could you please show some example data and how you would like it to look.Thanks

Comment: Please read how to ask a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> re: What I want to be able to do is have a macro that checks the first value in the column (ie the title) and if it doesn't match one of a predetermined list delete the whole column along with it's data.

To delete all columns **NOT WITHIN** the list:

```
Sub del_cols()
    Dim c As Long, vCOL_LBLs As Variant

    vCOL_LBLs = Array("BCD", "CDE", "DEF")

    With Worksheets("Sheet7")       '<~~ set this worksheet reference properly!
        For c = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(1, c), vCOL_LBLs, 0)) Then
                .Columns(c).Delete
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

To delete all columns **WITHIN** the list:

```
Sub del_cols()
    Dim v As Long, vCOL_LBLs As Variant

    vCOL_LBLs = Array("BCD", "CDE", "DEF")

    With Worksheets("Sheet7")       '<~~ set this worksheet reference properly!
        For v = LBound(vCOL_LBLs) To UBound(vCOL_LBLs)
            Do While Not IsError(Application.Match(vCOL_LBLs(v), .Rows(1), 0))
                .Cells(1, Application.Match(vCOL_LBLs(v), .Rows(1), 0)).EntireColumn.Delete
            Loop
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great it does what I want except that it deletes the cells I state in the "Array" section, is there something small I would change so that I can it's the values I enter there are the ones that are left rather than removed? Thanks!

Comment: My apologies; apparently I reversed your original conditions. See above for correction.